# The New li can't be added

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking at it and I can't see the reason why the new li is not being added. I am trying to add an li element to the list, but for some reason i can't manage to do it

```js
function myFunction() {
  var thelist = document.getElementById("myOl");
  var newli = document.createElement("li");
  newli.text = "mytext";
  thelist.add(newli);
}
```

```html
<ol id="myOl">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `add` is not a property of an element object

Comment: You obviously didn't even check your JS console for errors. Downvoting for this.

Comment: try .appendChild(newli);  instead of .add

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunction() {
   var thelist = document.getElementById("myOl");
   var newli = document.createElement("li");
   newli.textContent = "mytext";
   thelist.appendChild(newli);
}
```

```html
<ol id="myOl">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard and doesn't exist in some browsers. Use `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newli.innerText = "mytext";
thelist.append(newli);
```

Your error was using `.text` instead of `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` and using the incorrect function `add` instead of `append`

Edit: `.textContent` would be better than `innerText` as per @Barmar

Comment: `innerText` is not standard and doesn't work in some browsers. Use `textContent`.

Comment: well thanks! there is no object such as text right? or add? can I use .add somewhere else ?

Comment: `append()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method.

Comment: @C.Unbay -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add

Comment: @Barmar wonder why it worked in jsbin? https://jsbin.com/miyowayujo/edit?html,output

Comment: I'll still take the heat for not knowing the difference between jQuery and javascript, the cardinal sin of StackOverflow

Comment: I can't find any documentation for it, I suspect it's an archaic method that's still supported for backward compatibility.

Comment: yeah apparently the method goes for both

Comment: @Barmar, they should keep it, anyway. :) This append() mistery is interesting, really. Chrome and FF support it, IE 11 unfortunately not. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `li` node then  a text node then append the text to `li` which will be appended to the `ul`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var li = document.createElement("LI");
  var newli = document.createTextNode("text");
  li.appendChild(newli);
  document.getElementById("myOl").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ol id="myOl">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```